# redirect stdout to file and insert string every other line

Tags: c, stdout, dup2

Im writing a program using C wherein in executing system commands using POPEN.
Write the output of every command to a file.
I want to be able to write to the same file and number the output of the commands.

Here's the output that Im aiming to do.

Assuming the commands that I want to run is..

1) ls
2) bash -version

So the output that I want looks something like this..

```
1) ls

*file.txt    file2.txt    file3.txt     file4.txt

2) bash -version

GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

This is the code that I made:

```
FILE * out = NULL;
char * com = malloc(2000);
char * execCom = malloc(30000);
char * comR = malloc(2000);
strcpy(execCom, commands);
FILE * fp = NULL;

//remove("conf.txt")

out=fopen("com.txt","w");
dup2(fileno(out),1);
//run command and redirect the output to the file specified
if (execCom!=NULL)  
{
    fp=popen(com1,"w");
    fwrite(com2, 1,strlen(com2),fp);
    fwrite(com3, 1, strlen(com3),fp);

// get the first token 
com = strtok(execCom, "\n");

// walk through other tokens 
while( com != NULL ) 
{

    strcpy(comR,"\0");
    strcat(comR,com);
    strcat(comR,"\n");
    printf("%s",comR);

    //execute command
    fwrite(comR, 1, strlen(comR),fp);
    com = strtok(NULL, "\n");

}

pclose(fp);
fclose(out);
```

}

I was able to redirect the output of stdout to a file and I used dup2 to achieve this. Then knowing that dup2 redirects stdout to file, I used printf, print the string that I want to insert in the file (I was expecting that the string in the printf will be redirected to the same file and insert it in the place that I want but it didnt.)

Here's what I get..
Yes, the output was redirected to the file as well as the string in the printf. But, as you can see below, it is not formatted the way I want it to be...

```
*file.txt    file2.txt    file3.txt     file4.txt
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
1) ls
2) bash -version
```

How will I be able to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Why `dup2` when you simply can use `fprintf` or `dprintf` ?

Comment: @Chnossos Im not sure If I understood your reply to my question. So what I did was use "dprintf" and write the command that I need in the 2nd param, let's say "ls". When I execute the program, It writes the "ls" string to the text file but not the output of this command. I was expecting that it will redirect the output of ls command to the file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542750(v=vs.85).aspx The link is about dprintf and says that it works the same as printf which is not what I need. Thanks